# IEnumerable<SelectListItem> error in Simple Membership in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I use Simple Membership in ASP.NET MVC 5 to use my existing SQL Server. In Register page I use dropdownbox to polpulate the user roles. In my Account controller I use [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] for Register Action. When I run my web app and goto Register page I can see my DropDownBox poplulated with data from my SqlServer.

But when I try to create new user and select a role I get error as;

"**There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'roleName'**"

Here is my **Account Controller code**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SimpleMemberShip.Models;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SimpleMemberShip.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // ****** REGISTER PAGE ACTION ******
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            //Roles for DropDown Box
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles(), "roleName");
            ViewData["roleName"] = RolesList;
            return View();
        }

        // ****** REGISTER PAGE ACTION with PARAMETERS ******
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(Register registerdata, string RoleName)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(registerdata.Username, registerdata.Password);
                    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(registerdata.Username, RoleName);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException exception)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Warning: Username exist...");
                    return View(registerdata);
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Warning: Username exist....");
            return View(registerdata);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the my **Register.cshtml code** look like:

```
@using SimpleMemberShip.Models
@model Register

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>New User Registration</h2>
<br />
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <label>User Name:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        <label>User Password:</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <br />
        <label>Roles</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("roleName", (System.Web.Mvc.SelectList)ViewBag.roleName, "Select a Role")
        <br />
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    }
</div>
```

Does anyone know where I am making mistakes?

Kind Regards,

Comment: When the POST fails and you try to `return View(registerdata)`, the ViewBag is empty so the dropdownlist can't be populated. As an aside, you should include the selectlist in the `Register` ViewModel and not use the ViewBag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What most likely happens in that you have some kind of error in the way you register a user, and the validation fails. In that case you are returning the same view, which is fine:

```
return View(registerdata);
```

However you are not repopulating the `ViewData["roleName"]` element which the view depends on. Since ASP.NET MVC does not maintain any kind of state, this element needs to be repopulated on each request. So consider doing that, exactly the same way you were doing it before in the GET action, and the error should go away.

As a side note, you are mixing two ways of passing data from controller into view, model and ViewData. This is not very maintainable and obvious, so I suggest you stick to model approach only. Which should not be very hard - add a list of role names as a property of the model, and make sure to initialize it on every request.

Answer (score 1):

In your HttpPost action, If some error happens, or if your model validation fails, you are returning the same model to the same view. So you need to reload the `ViewData["roleName"]` with the Role list collection again as your view is trying to read from it to load the dropdown.

Remember, HTTP is stateless. ASP.NET MVC does not work like web forms where it stores the form data in view state across multiple http requests(form posts)

My recommendation is to not use dynamic stuff like ViewBag and ViewData. You should be using a strongly typed viewmodel to transfer data from your action methopd to your views.

so create a view model like

```
public class CreateUser
{
  public string UserName {set;get;}
  public string Password{set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> RolesList {set;get;}
  public int SelectedRoleId {set;get;}
}
```

And in your GET action method, You get all the roles ( Which could be a collection of Role class or some custom class), convert that to a collection of `SelectListItem` and assign that to the `RolesList` property of the CreateUser object

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  var vm=new CreateUser();     
  vm.RolesList =GetRoles();

  return View(vm);     
}
private List<SelectListItem> GetRoles()
{
   var allRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();        
   return allRoles.Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = s.roleId.ToString(),
            Text = s.roleName
        });
}
```

and in your razor view which is bound to `CreateUser` class.

```
@using YourNamespace.CreateUser
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Password)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.SelectedRoleId, Model.RolesList,"Select")
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

And now in your Http post action method, Make sure you reload the `RolesList` collection before you return the posted model back to the same view (If Mode Validation fails or an Exception occurs)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(CreateUser model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {
       // to do : Save something
      // read model.UserName & model.SelectedRoleId etc. 
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
      catch (MembershipCreateUserException exception)
      {
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "Warning: Username exist...");
          //Reload the data now
          model.RolesList =GetRoles();
          return View(model);
      }
   }
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Warning: Username exist....");
  //Reload the data now
   model.RolesList =GetRoles();
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi Shyju, I try to use your code but I get and error on RoleManger as "The name 'RoleManger' does not exist in the current context". Also on s.RoleId and s.RoleName has error. It says "string does not contains definition for RoleId and RoleName". I am using VS2015 Communtity and used .Net Framework 4.5 to created MVC with no authentication. I install Install-Package WebMatrix.Data and Install-Package WebMatrix.WebData for my project. As well as Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers and Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data. Thats why I cannot find RoleManager. Any help?

Comment: @NTMS: That line is not needed. I updated the answer. Also in `GetRoles` method, replace RoleID and RoleName with properties of the object you get from `Roles.GetAllRoles()` method

Comment: Thank you for comment. System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles(); just returns a my sql serverb database table data. I couldn find any properties for this. And is true my sql table contains only RoleId and RoleName. !!!